# How to prevent unsolicited user behavior on image radio button?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, users, selection, actions

Below you can see a section from a booking system.

[image: Staff's Photo, Name and a Button to Call]

In this section users should be able to select a staff to book and also call him when they need. However, we received feedback about that some users clicked on the "call" button to select the staff instead of selecting the staff by clicking on the photo.

[image: This is how a selected image radio button looks like.]

The question is, what should be done to prevent this user misconception?

Comment: So, there's two functions, correct? I can call them right then and there, or book an appt instead?

Comment: There are two functions in a box. First, you can select the staff by clicking on his photo. Second, you can call the staff by clicking on the "Call" button.

Comment: And you can select multiple staff, but obviously call only one at a time, correct? Is there a dominant action?

Comment: Oh no. I mean radio button not checkbox. (I'll fix it right now.) So, you can select only one staff at a time.

Comment: and you call any of them by clicking on his "Call" button when needed.

Comment: It's not the users "misconception". That's exactly what I would do, too. There is a call button, of course I click the call button. Why is there a call button? But the answer of @MikeM should fix **your** misconception.

Comment: @marvinpoo After days, I totally agree with you about that it's not a matter of misconception. The answer of MikeM was my very first plan but I expected to find better solutions (e.g. with less buttons) than I can think, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't overload actions onto images**, unless you *want* users to accidentally perform unwanted actions.  Allow calls, and other actions, only *after* a selection has been made.

**Add a call confirmation** before beginning the call.  This could be in the form of showing info that users can choose to act on, such as selecting which of multiple email addresses or phone numbers to use.

Answer (score 4):

## Try separating a multistep action (booking flow) from an immediate one (calling) with explicit actions.

In this case, one path leads to an immediate (desired?) interruption for the staff: You're calling them.

The other path is a booking. I'm assuming there's a separate, at least 1 step path to completion.

[image]

## Tradeoffs

- The extra buttons do add more visual elements
- The button labels surface each explicit action

Comment: This seems to be the most accurate option.

Comment: If the *primary* action is expected to be booking an appointment, consider making "Call now" not look like a button with similar importance.  Perhaps try making it a hyperlink, possibly with additional information (e.g. "Call for more details" or whatever the intended purpose for calling is).

Answer (score 2):

I would have done the same, in your explanation you say each one of those images are two buttons, but what its see is an image with its corresponding button. Plus, the call button contrast gives a greater visual presence than the rest of the elements.

Perhaps finding some way to create two buttons without altering  too much the design giving more importance to the *select button* and visually relegating to a second instance the *call button*:

[image]

Comment: The white square is not perceived as a checkbox, not until one other entry is checked. It looks like an input field to me, where I can type a number, for example. I think that the concept of booking implies a schedule, so you agree in advance when the appointment takes place. In that case, replacing the checkbox with a calendar icon might be a better way to convey its purpose.

Comment: If this is for mobile, having two small clickable regions next to each other is problematic.